# My local files from my TFS are not marked as read only

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have some projects under TFS. Most of them have their local version (on my hard drive) marked as read-only. I don't know why but some of them (from specific project) have their local version not marked as read only. I already try to delete them and perform a 'Get latest version' I also try a 'Get specific version'. No luck so far.

I'm using the online version of tfs: https://xxx.visualstudio.com/

Any idea why?

Thank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I just ran into my problem myself. It seems you're setup as a local workspace. I found this [article](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/11/02/local-workspaces-in-tfs-2012.aspx) extremely helpful.

Answer (score -1):

this sounds like files been edited without checkout or in another editor(notepad for example)

- 'Get latest version' will not work in this case
- 'Get specific version - Latest version' should do the trick
- as last resort: backup modified files, unmap(delete all), map(get all)

Comment: I already tried all these things. No luck. Very strange. I also try to clear the TFS local cache.

Comment: Strange. Seems that you are left without solution, you could check HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\SourceControl properties to see if they differ ("WritableOnGet") on your computer or see what is so special about that folder, a new file added to it has the same behaviour?

Comment: I have the value 0 for WritableOnGet. Is it normal?

Comment: Yes, default value. No more ideas